# I think I bricked my SSD and my laptop won't turn on (reposting from the electronics stackexchange)

Tags: linux, boot, laptop, ssd

I am not exactly sure where to post this as a lot of things happened so I'll just go through everything.

1. I tried installing Gentoo
2. I typed "emerge-webrsync"
3. My laptop shut off.

4.I tried turning it back on and nothing happened. No light just a 'shuck' sound where the SSD is. I can't boot to BIOS. Nothing happens except that sound.

5. I removed the SSD and plugged it into my desktop and now the desktop isnt turning on as well. No fan spin. No light. Nothing. Even if I remove it nothing happens.

I'm scared. What can I do? Repair shop?

If you need to know my hardware, my laptop is a Dell Vostro 5990. I have no idea how gentoo could have caused this. I just typed the command, grabbed a glass of water and it died.

Comment: Don't use it as the main drive on your desktop. Try and use it as a secondary drive. As I recommend to a lot of people, don't be experimenting with Linux distros on your main computer for fun. I know way to many people who end up in some sort of pickle. If you're newer to Linux and want to experiment with distros, use a virtual machine.

Comment: Your Desktop should post even with a bad HDD or SSD. Sounds like all your equipment got nuked by an electrical problem. The only thing I can think of is that your SSD is somehow returning power to the board like an accidental "USB Killer"

Comment: Oh god... is it fixable?

Answer (score 1):

There are two paths to take. Given that you are scared, I suggest the first one since it is the easiest and most likely to help:

Take it to repair. Contact Dell to find an Authorized Repair Center near you or send it to them for service.

The other is debug this by asking a series of questions, trying different things until your problem is either fixed or giving up. That's good to learn but will cost you a lot more in time than it will save in money. If you want, start by asking yourself: *What is the worse that could happen?* If it is mostly replacing an SSD because you have your important and irreplaceable data backed up, go ahead and try these things:

- Place the SSD in an external USB enclosure and connect it to your desktop. In the best case scenario, it will mount automatically and you can access your data that way. This is unlikely but it is important to try this first as it will give you a hint as to what happened:
- If you mounted the SSD and it does absolutely nothing. Nothing lights up, even for a brief moment, then you have a dead SSD. Nothing to do but to replace it. The command you typed itself is not directly the issue but if your SSD was faulty and about to die, installing a distro which requires plenty of I/O likely precipitated the issue.
- If the enclosure lights up but the SSD does not mount, open a disk partitioning tool such as GParted. The drive may show up there as unallocated or unpartitioned space. This is a good sign. Sometimes disks get formatted in a way that is not compatible between systems and so you will not be able to read data from it without repartioning and **therefore losing all your data**.   This can happen because the controller logically maps sector sizes while the other system does not. It is also possible that you cannot read the drive data because it is an encrypted disk and the key is in the firmware of your laptop. If that is the case, then you'll have to get support from Dell. This is most likely since you have a *business* laptop.
- If the disk appears but you cannot write to it or even partioning is disabled, then the disk is probably dead.
- If the disk appears with an accessible partition, you can try to repair it by running fsck or another similar file-system checker tool. Afterwards, you should definitely check with smartmon/smartctl to verify that the disk is not dying anyway and have to repeat the ordeal soon after.

Comment: Thank you so much. I guess I'll have to go get a new ssd. Thank god for cloud storage though. And thanks again for your help.